# Trino testcontainer fails on docker version 19.x and successfully loaded on docker version 20.x

Tags: docker, containers, testcontainers, trino

On docker version "Server Version: 19.03.8" trino testcontainer fails, but with docker version docker version "Server Version: 20.10.18" successfully started.

```
 D:2022-11-16 09:30:47.809 L:ERROR C:docker[trinodb/trino:latest] F:GenericContainer.java(531) Fn:tryStart T:main R: - Log output from the failed container:
11:30:55 11:30:55 + launcher_opts=(--etc-dir /etc/trino)
11:30:55 11:30:55 + grep -s -q node.id /etc/trino/node.properties
11:30:55 11:30:55 + launcher_opts+=("-Dnode.id=${HOSTNAME}")
11:30:55 11:30:55 + exec /usr/lib/trino/bin/launcher run --etc-dir /etc/trino -Dnode.id=e3cbef28ab27
11:30:55 11:30:55 ERROR: Java is not installed
11:30:55 11:30:55 11:30:55 11:30:55 [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 160.744 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.radcom.queryexecutor.integration.TrinoIntegrationTest
11:30:55 11:30:55 [ERROR] com.radcom.queryexecutor.integration.TrinoIntegrationTest  Time elapsed: 160.743 s  <<< ERROR!
11:30:55 11:30:55 org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
11:30:55 11:30:55 Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
11:30:55 11:30:55 Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
11:30:55 11:30:55 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container exited with code 4
11:30:55 11:30:55
```

From documentation I see that the minimum docker version is Docker v17.09, Is the docker version is my problem here?

I was expected trino testcontainer to work on docker version 19.x  https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed caused by the old docker. However, the `trinodb/trino` docker image requires a newer docker, not the testcontainers library.
See [this trino github issue](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/14269) for more details.